# How to load user-specific configuration for CMake project

Tags: configuration, cmake

I like to use a configuration file that sets several cached variables. The purpose is to reuse it for every projects running on a machine or to select different library versions for testing or special purpose.

I can achieve it with a CMake file like this one:

```
set(path_to_lib_one path/to/lib/one)
set(option1 dont_want_to_bother_setting_this_option)
set(option2 that_option_have_to_be_set_again)
```

And call `include(myConfigfile)`.

But I would like to know if their is a cache-like way of doing it and what are the best practices to manage user/setup specific configurations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the initial cache option offered by CMake. You store your options in the right format (`set with`CACHE`) and call

```
cmake -C <cacheFile> <pathToSourceDir>
```

## Self-contained example

The `CMakeLists.txt` looks like

```
project(blabla)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)

message("${path_to_lib_one} / ${option1} / ${option2}")
```

and you want to pre-set the three variables. The `cacheFile.txt` looks like

```
set(path_to_lib_one path/to/lib/one CACHE FILEPATH "some path")
set(option1 "dont_want_to_bother_setting_this_option" CACHE STRING "some option 1")
set(option2 42 CACHE INT "and an integer")
```

and your CMake call (from a directory `build` below the source directory)

```
cmake -C cacheFile.txt ..
```

The output is

```
loading initial cache file ../cacheFile.txt
[..]
path/to/lib/one / dont_want_to_bother_setting_this_option / 42
```

Documentation:
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#options

## Load external cache files

Additionally, CMake offer a way to read in a cache file, that was created by another project. The command is `load_cache`. You can use it to just load the variables from the external cache or to copy them to the cache of the current project.

Documentation: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/load_cache.html

Comment: From the doc you pointed out: > The given file should be a CMake script containing SET commands that use the CACHE option, not a cache-format file.

Comment: Weird error... CMake Error: The source directory "D:/1-build-dev/qt-python-cmake/CMakeCache2.txt" is a file, not a directory.

Comment: Thanks, great answer!. But I was primarily wondering if their is a way to read *cache-like* files. Containing this kind of statements: ````option1:STRING= "dont_want_to_bother_setting_this_option"```` etc.

Comment: It is already implemented in cmake because it read CMakeCache.txt! But Why is it not possible to use this feature?

Comment: Nice! That's exactly what is was looking for.

Comment: How to modify cache var from cache file?